# How to serialize and save POST request from JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django-rest-framework

I'm sending a post request from JavaScript. The request is an array of objects. If I don't stringify the request, Django doesn't return what I'm actually sending. It only returns [Object object] and I cannot access the data.

What I've tried:

1. created a function on `views.py` that allows me to identify the request and its content, format the content and pass it as an argument to serializer to perform the request.
2. Separate fields in 2 different models and create 2 serializers nesting one in the other and then creating a function to perform the creation

```
# views.py
def perform_create(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        post_request = self.request.POST['registers']
        print(post_request)
        a = json.loads(post_request)
        serialized_data = request.data
        request.data['item1'] = a['item1']
        request.data['item2'] = a['item2']
        request.data['photo1'] = a['photo1']
        request.data['photo2'] = a['photo2']
        print(request.data)
        serializer = InstalationReportSerializer(data=request.data, many= True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data )
        return Response(serializer._errors)
```

```
# models.py
class ModelContained(CommonInfo):
    item1 = models.CharField(
        _('item1'),max_length=200, db_column='item_1', blank=True, 
        null=True, help_text=_('item 1'),)
    item2 = models.CharField(
        _('item2'), max_length=200, db_column='item_2', blank=True, 
        null=True, help_text=_('item 2'),)


class ModelContainer(CommonInfo):
    header = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelContained, 
        verbose_name=_('header'),db_column='random_name',
        on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='random',
        related_query_name='random',help_text=_('contained model')
    )
    initial_photos = models.ImageField(
        _('initial_photos'), db_column='initial_photos', blank=True,
        null=True, upload_to='photo/', help_text=_('before'))
    end_photos = models.ImageField(
        _('end_photos'), db_column='end_photos', blank=True, null=True,
        upload_to='photo', help_text=_('after'))
```

```
# serializer.py
  class ModelContainerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = ModelContainer
        fields = (
            'header', 'initial_photos', 'end_photos'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id')

ModelContainedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
registers = ModelContainerSerializer(source='ModelContainer_set', many = True)

    class Meta: 
        model = ModelContained
        fields = (
            'id', 'item1', 'item2','registers'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        registers_render = validated_data.pop('registers')
        register = InstallationReport.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return register
```

The front-end is sending:

```
{
  item1: "someinfo",
  item2: "another info",
  registers: Array(1)
}
```

The array contains:

```
0:
end_photos: File {name: "WhatsApp Image 2019-05-14 at 5.28.02 PM(3).jpeg", lastModified: 1557873045827, lastModifiedDate: Tue May 14 2019 17:30:45 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 124922, …}
initial_photos: File {name: "WhatsApp Image 2019-05-14 at 5.28.00 PM.jpeg", lastModified: 1557872985264, lastModifiedDate: Tue May 14 2019 17:29:45 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 99106, …}
```

Comment: Why not stringily the frontend request?

Comment: Because file fields disappear and it only allows 1 form, front-end send an array of  fields, so most of the time is sending 2 or more forms, when stringify, the second form generates an error 'Invalid json'

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you send and receive the data in the client code, it's a little difficult to diagnose the problem here. However, `[object Object]` is the `toString` representation of a Plain Old JavaScript Object: it's what, for example, this code will emit:

```
const foo = {};
console.log(foo.toString());
```

You'll get this in your render any time you attempt to output an object where a string should be. I submit, therefore, that your problem is not in the backend code at all, but simply what you do with the data once it returns to you. Chances are a quick look at your *Network* tab in browser development tools would be enough to prove it, but you could also try a simple `JSON.stringify(theReturnedData)` in the client code prior to displaying it.